# LWC Override for Omniscript Text Element is not working properly

Tags: lightning-web-components, omnistudio

I Have written a simple lwc override for the Text Element
Code :

```
**HTML** :

<template>
  <slot>
    <vlocity_ins-input if:false={rendering}
             type={_inputType}
             class={_styleClasses.input}
             label={_propSetMap.label}
             onblur={handleBlur}
             required={_propSetMap.required}
             required-label={allCustomLabelsUtil.OmniRequired}
             max-length={_maxLength}
             min-length={_minLength}
             pattern={_patternVal}
             theme={_theme}
             tab-index={tabIndex}
             field-level-help={_handleHelpText}
             field-level-help-position={_propSetMap.helpTextPos}
             icon-name="utility:info"
             placeholder={_placeholder}
             message-when-value-missing={_messageWhenValueMissing}
             message-when-pattern-mismatch={_messageWhenPatternMismatch}
             message-when-too-short={_messageWhenTooShort}
             message-when-too-long={_messageWhenTooLong}
             message-when-bad-input={_messageWhenBadInput}
             message-when-range-overflow={_messageWhenRangeOverflow}
             message-when-range-underflow={_messageWhenRangeUnderflow}
             message-when-step-mismatch={_messageWhenStepMismatch}
             message-when-type-mismatch={_messageWhenTypeMismatch}
             autocomplete={_autocomplete}
             value={elementValue}
             name={_name}
             data-omni-input>
      <template if:true={_propSetMap.repeat}>
        <span slot="label"
              style="bottom:7px; right:-11px;"
              class={_styleClasses.repeatContainer}
              role="group">
          <button if:true={canRepeat}
                  class={_styleClasses.repeatAdd}
                  onclick={handleAdd}>
            <vlocity_ins-icon icon-name="utility:add"
                    alternative-text={_repeatAlternativeText}
                    extraclass={_styleClasses.repeatIcons}
                    size="xx-small">
            </vlocity_ins-icon>
          </button>
          <button if:true={canRemove}
                  class={_styleClasses.repeatRemove}
                  onclick={handleRemove}>
            <vlocity_ins-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                    alternative-text={_removeAlternativeText}
                    extraclass={_styleClasses.repeatIcons}
                    size="xx-small">
            </vlocity_ins-icon>
          </button>
        </span>
      </template>
    </vlocity_ins-input>
    <vlocity_ins-masked-input if:true={_isMasked}
                    class={_styleClasses.input}
                    type={_inputType}
                    label={_propSetMap.label}
                    onblur={handleBlur}
                    required={_propSetMap.required}
                    required-label={allCustomLabelsUtil.OmniRequired}
                    max-length={_maxLength}
                    min-length={_minLength}
                    pattern={_patternVal}
                    imask={_imaskTextAttributes}
                    theme={_theme}
                    tab-index={tabIndex}
                    field-level-help={_handleHelpText}
                    field-level-help-position={_propSetMap.helpTextPos}
                    placeholder={_placeholder}
                    message-when-value-missing={_messageWhenValueMissing}
                    message-when-pattern-mismatch={_messageWhenPatternMismatch}
                    message-when-too-short={_messageWhenTooShort}
                    message-when-too-long={_messageWhenTooLong}
                    message-when-bad-input={_messageWhenBadInput}
                    message-when-range-overflow={_messageWhenRangeOverflow}
                    message-when-range-underflow={_messageWhenRangeUnderflow}
                    message-when-step-mismatch={_messageWhenStepMismatch}
                    message-when-type-mismatch={_messageWhenTypeMismatch}
                    message-when-mask-incomplete={_messageWhenMaskIncomplete}
                    value={elementValue}
                    autocomplete={_autocomplete}
                    name={_name}
                    data-omni-input>
      <template if:true={_propSetMap.repeat}>
        <span slot="label"
              style="bottom:7px; right:-11px;"
              class={_styleClasses.repeatContainer}
              role="group">
          <button if:true={canRepeat}
                  class={_styleClasses.repeatAdd}
                  onclick={handleAdd}>
            <vlocity_ins-icon icon-name="utility:add"
                    alternative-text={_repeatAlternativeText}
                    extraclass={_styleClasses.repeatIcons}
                    size="xx-small">
            </vlocity_ins-icon>
          </button>
          <button if:true={canRemove}
                  class={_styleClasses.repeatRemove}
                  onclick={handleRemove}>
            <vlocity_ins-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                    alternative-text={_removeAlternativeText}
                    extraclass={_styleClasses.repeatIcons}
                    size="xx-small">
            </vlocity_ins-icon>
          </button>
        </span>
      </template>
    </vlocity_ins-masked-input>
  </slot>
</template> 




**Javascript** :

import omniscriptText from 'vlocity_ins/omniscriptText';
import template from './normalTextOverride.html';
export default class normalTextOverride extends omniscriptText {

 handleBlur(evt) {
        let valueOfElement = evt.target.value;
        this.applyCallResp(valueOfElement.toLowerCase());
    }
 render() {
        return template;
    }
} 

**XML** :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<masterLabel>normalTextOverride</masterLabel>
<runtimeNamespace>vlocity_ins</runtimeNamespace>
<targets>
<target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
<target>lightning__AppPage</target>
<target>lightning__HomePage</target>
</targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Functionality of this code is that, it is making the text entered in lowercase.
Note : The text field is required.

Screenshot of Text Field in Omniscript:
[image]

When I Enter "**QWERTY**" , it changes the value to "**qwerty**", which is working fine.

Screenshot :
[image]

BUT If I Again enter "**QWERTY**" , it does not renders it back to "**querty**" , it stays "**QWERTY**" in UI although Omniscript Data JSON shows "**querty**".
Screenshot :

[image]

Second time , If I enter the same text,it should have rendered it to lowerCase as the Code is written, but it is not doing so.

Is this bug from vlocity side?
Kindly Please suggest anything how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :

We need to make the html render in javascript :

Code Changed :

Javascript :

```
handleBlur(evt) {
        let valueOfElement = evt.target.value;
        this.applyCallResp(valueOfElement.toLowerCase());
        this.template.querySelector('vlocity_ins-input').value
        =valueOfElement.toLowerCase();
    }
```

I still dont have idea , if we do not override html then what needs to be done. But if we are overriding the html as above code , this solution works.